# Robolectric flaky tests

Tags: android, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I'm new to Robolectric and also to my new project, which has been written with extensive Robolectric tests.

I did a ./gradlew clean test and found tests were failing randomly. I suspect there is something wrong with the @Before code but not sure what.

Here is an example of the error JUnit is reporting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must be called from main thread of process
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1411)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.dispatchMessage(ShadowMessageQueue.java:130)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.access$100(ShadowMessageQueue.java:30)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue$1.run(ShadowMessageQueue.java:95)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(Scheduler.java:269)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.runOneTask(Scheduler.java:179)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.advanceTo(Scheduler.java:160)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.advanceBy(Scheduler.java:143)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.unPause(Scheduler.java:54)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.unPause(ShadowLooper.java:266)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:306)
at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$2.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:45)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:118)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:129)
at com.acme.android.util.FragmentRule.before(FragmentRule.java:77)
at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:46)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:298)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here's the code for the Fragment rule:

```
public class FragmentRule<F extends Fragment, A extends NavigationDrawerActivity> extends ExternalResource {

private final Class<A> activityClass;
private A activity;
private F fragment;
private String initialFragmentTag = "transaction";

private FragmentRule(Class<A> activityClass) {
    this.activityClass = activityClass;
}

public static <F extends Fragment, A extends NavigationDrawerActivity> FragmentRule<F, A> newInstance(Class<A> a) {
    return new FragmentRule<>(a);
}

public static <F extends Fragment, A extends NavigationDrawerActivity> FragmentRule<F, A> forFragment(F fragment, Class<A> a) {
    FragmentRule<F, A> rule = new FragmentRule<>(a);
    rule.fragment = fragment;
    return rule;
}

public static <F extends Fragment> FragmentRule<F, FragmentActivity> newInstance() {
    return FragmentRule.newInstance(FragmentActivity.class);
}

public static <F extends Fragment> FragmentRule<F, FragmentActivity> forFragment(F fragment) {
    return FragmentRule.forFragment(fragment, FragmentActivity.class);
}

private static synchronized void initActivity(Activity activity, Fragment fragment, String initialFragmentTag) {
    activity.getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
        .addToBackStack(initialFragmentTag)
        .commit();
    ShadowLooper.unPauseMainLooper();
}

public F withFragment(F fragment) {
    return withFragment(fragment, initialFragmentTag);
}

public F withFragment(F fragment, String tag) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
    this.initialFragmentTag = tag;
    initActivity(activity, fragment, initialFragmentTag);
    return fragment;
}

public A getActivity() {
    return activity;
}

@Override
protected void before() throws Throwable {
    activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(activityClass)
        .withIntent(new Intent(ShadowApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), activityClass)
            .putExtra("enableProgressBar", false))
        .create()
        .start()
        .visible()
        .get();

    if (fragment != null) {
        initActivity(activity, fragment, initialFragmentTag);
    }
}

public <N extends Fragment> N getNextStartedFragment() {
    activity.getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    return (N) activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
}

public F getFragment() {
    return fragment;
}

public static class FragmentActivity extends NavigationDrawerActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        enableProgressBar = false;
    }
}}
```

Sorry for the wall of code, not sure where to start! The version of Robolectric is 3.0.